# How to find the average age in the given data

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

The following table shows the numer of patients admitted in a hospital with different age groups.

[image]

Question : What is the average age for which maximum cases occurred ?

My approach :
We can see that maximum cases occurred between the age group of 35-45

Now how to proceed further, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the formula for mode?

Comment: Yes, but what is the role of mode here...

Comment: When you're looking for maximum frequency, you find mode

Comment: Here we have maximum cases occurred in age group 35-45

Answer (score 1):

Since we have to find maximum cases, we need to find mode. For grouped data,
$$Mode=l+\left({{f_1-f_0}\over {2f_1-f_0-f_2}} \right)\times h$$
Where
 $l=$Lower interval of modal class
$f_1=$Frequency of modal class
$f_0=$Frequency of class preceding modal class
$f_2=$Frequency of class succeeding modal class
$h=$Class size
Here, modal class is $35-45$, so

$l=35$
$f_1=23$
$f_0=21$
$f_2=14$
$h=10$

Putting these values into the formula, we get $$Mode=36.81$$